# Why do web-services usually working XML or JSON formatted information?

Tags: json, xml, web-services

I'm new to web-services and have done some research but haven't found the answer I want. I would be happy if you could write an article about it in detail or briefly explain why. What is the purpose of using Json or Xml here? And I want to know exactly what functional differences exist between them.

Answer (score 1):

1. The information has to be returned in some kind of format.
2. Using a standard format is better than using a non-standard format because it enables reuse of widely-available parsers.
3. XML was rapidly adopted around 2000 for the purpose because it was vendor-neutral and met the technical requirements.
4. JSON came along later and started to displace XML because it was simpler: it was simpler because it was designed specifically for handling structured data, whereas XML had been designed primarily with structured documents in mind.
5. Among the many features available in XML with no equivalent in JSON, the ones that stand out are DTD-based validation, entities and entity references, mixed content, comments and processing instructions, and namespaces. These features are all very useful for document processing, but not for interchanging structured data.